# Sort HTML elements by their tag ids

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

There are some tags and I need to sort them to display in alphabetical order by id using JavaScript(without jQuery).

```
<div id="tags">
   <p id="b"></p>
   <p id="a"></p>
   <p id="d"></p>
   <p id="c"></p>
</div>
```

Here is how it must look:

```
<div id="tags">
     <p id="a"></p>
     <p id="b"></p> 
     <p id="c"></p>
     <p id="d"></p>
</div>
```

I tried using sort() method to sort ids and then rearranged them by insertBefore() inside for loop. But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can recreate the HTML after sorting

```js
var ps = document.querySelectorAll( "#tags p" );

var sortedPs = Array.from( ps ).sort( (a, b) => a.id.localeCompare( b.id ) ); //sort the ps

document.querySelector( "#tags" ).innerHTML = sortedPs.map( s => s.outerHTML ).join(""); //recreate the markup
```

```html
<div id="tags">
   <p id="b">b</p>
   <p id="a">a</p>
   <p id="d">d</p>
   <p id="c">c</p>
</div>
```

**Note**

- This will remove all existing events binded on the existing p's.
- To retain them, use `appendChild` instead of `innerHTML`

**To retain events after soring**

```js
var ps = document.querySelectorAll( "#tags p" );

var sortedPs = Array.from( ps ).sort( (a, b) => a.id.localeCompare( b.id ) ); //sort the ps

var tags = document.querySelector( "#tags" );

//create a duplicate hollow tags

var dupTags = tags.cloneNode(false);
sortedPs.forEach( s => dupTags.appendChild ( s ) );

//replace old with new tags
tags.parentNode.replaceChild(dupTags ,tags);
```

```html
<div id="tags">
   <p id="b">b</p>
   <p id="a">a</p>
   <p id="d">d</p>
   <p id="c">c</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @gurvinder372 answer more but this is another way to go about it.

```js
function element_sort(id)
{
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  var f = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var ids = [];

  var i = 0;
  var l = e.getElementsByTagName('p').length;

  while (i < l)
  {
    ids.push(e.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].id);
    f.appendChild(e.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]);
    i++
  }

  ids.sort();

  for (var i = 0; i <= ids.length; i++)
  {
    for (var j = 0; j < f.childNodes.length; j++)
    {
      if (f.childNodes[j].id==ids[i]) {
        e.appendChild(f.childNodes[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
element_sort("tags")
```

```html
<div id="tags">
   <p id="b">b</p>
   <p id="a">a</p>
   <p id="d">d</p>
   <p id="c">c</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Andam, thank you, it works well, however if a child contains a child, it goes first. For example, if we insert a div here <p id="d">d<div>div</div></p> it appears at the top of the page.

Comment: @smus I dont know why it does that for div its fine with other elements such as span 
   <p id="b"><span>b</span></p>

Comment: @smus Why are you using div inside p anyway

Comment: ... but it works if I replace <p> by <section> Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Because I needed to test it with other elements inside. Your code works perfectly for my task! Big respect!